# Writing junit test case for CPU usage program

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have a java program which calculates the CPU usage of the environment(single machine) in which it is running. For that initially it creates a process and then calculates the usage based on the input stream reader.

What can be a success and failure test case in this situation.

I am new to junit and in writing test cases, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What are you even testing?  CPU load and how much work is being one on a machine means two completely different things to two completely different machines.

Comment: @Makoto: Sorry if the question was not put up in a proper way. I didnt understand what u said. Can you be little clear without getting annoyed.

Comment: I'm not particularly annoyed.  I'm wondering what you're trying to actually test.

Comment: ok. I am trying to test a program which when run on a single linux machine outputs its cpu share %. I want to know what is the possible test case for it in terms of junit as the result is always dynamic, so nothing can be expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decompose your problem into testable units. In your case you can test the parser, separately from the code that runs the external process. So you test, two things:

1. Test that your parser is returning the correct load value for different inputs
2. Test that you code is running the correct process

What you don't test is, that your code is returning the correct load value for the current situation, because:

- You do not know which value is correct
- You do not need to verify that the program you call is working correctly, but you want to test your code

The result is something like:

```
public void test45PercentLoad() {
  LoadParser p = new LoadParser();
  InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("cpuUsageSample45percentLoad.txt");
  p.read(in);
  assertEquals(45, p.getLoadPercentage());
}

public void testProgramCall() {
  Process p = MachineLoadMeter.callExternalProgram();
  assertEquals("process is terminated", !p.isAlive());
  assertEquals("exit value 0 means some program was run", 0, p.exitValue());
  // maybe test the process output for some string patterns
  // that are always present, to check that the correct external program
  // was run
}

/**
 * Run everything together, but only test basics.
 */
public void testMachineLoadMeter() {
  int v = MachineLoadMeter.getCurrentLoadPercentage();
  assertTrue(v >= 0 && v <= 100);
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but my code is not using machine load meter, it is as simple as this: `Process p = Runtime
     .getRuntime()
     .exec(new String[] { "sh", "-c",
       "top -b -n2 -d 0.5 | grep \"Cpu(s):\" | cut -d ',' -f 4 | cut -d '%' -f1|tail -1| tr -d ' '" });
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
   cpuIdle = reader.readLine();`

Comment: Yes, that's what I was expecting. You cannot test this in a sensible way if you do not split up your code. If you don't do it, then you can only call your method and test whether your result is in an acceptable range.